# Ruby/Buildr—unpack tar.gz2

Tags: ruby, compression, tar, buildr

I have setup an a »buildfile« which should use a dependency from a non Maven repo. To download I use the following:

```
LIB_VERSION = "1.9.2"
LIB_EXT = "tar.bz2"
LIB_URL = "https://lib.com/lib-#{LIB_VERSION}.#{LIB_EXT}"
LIB = artifact( "ĺib:lib:#{LIB_EXT}:widget:#{LIB_VERSION}" )
download( LIB => LIB_URL )
```

what works quite fine, but since the actual dependency is in the `tar.gz2`I need to unpack is and therefore I wrote:

```
test.with( LIB )
test.enhance do |task|
    Unzip.new(  _('dest/lib') => LIB.to_s ).include( '*' ).extract  
end
```

But this gives me:

```
Zip::ZipError : Zip end of central directory signature not found
```

I am using `ruby 1.9.3` on a `64 bit Linux` machine, how can I fix this?

n.b.: I tried to use [this](https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/libarchive-ruby) (which failed to install) and several other way to unpack, but all failed. How can I make unpacking happen?

Comment: `Unzip` is for `ZIP` archives. It sounds like you need something that can handle gzipped (or bzipped; you mention both) tar archives. I don't know what that would be off the top of my head, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: So my question should be: Which ruby-lib can unpack bz2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. How could I forget the power of ant…

```
test.with( LIB )
test.enhance do |task|
    ant('uncompress') do |a| 
      a.bunzip2( :src => LIB.to_s, :dest => _( 'dest/lib.tar' ) )
      a.untar( :src => _( 'dest/lib.tar' ), :dest => _( 'dest/lib' ) )
    end  
end
```